# Span width of parent div using CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

How do I get my `.inner-container` divs to span the `width` and `height`  of the parent content div? [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/EeaMEz)

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px 40px 40px;
  grid-template-areas: "m h h" "m c c" "m f f";
}

.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "three four"
}

.header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: #2b9083;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: m;
  background-color: #ff66cc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #66ccff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: #65704e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.quadrant-one {
  grid-area: one;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.quadrant-two {
  grid-area: two;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.quadrant-three {
  grid-area: three;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.quadrant-four {
  grid-area: four;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="menu">MENU</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="quadrant-one">I</div>
      <div class="quadrant-two">II</div>
      <div class="quadrant-three">III</div>
      <div class="quadrant-four">IV</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am just curious to know why did you try `height:100%` but not `width:100%`?

Answer (score 0):

Set inner container width to 100%, you already have height set correctly.

```
   .inner-container {
    width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue:

Just add `width: 100%;` to `.inner-container`

```css
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 40px 40px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "m h h"
    "m c c"
    "m f f";
}
.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "one two"
    "three four"
}

.header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: #2b9083;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: m;
  background-color: #ff66cc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #66ccff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: #65704e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.quadrant-one {
    grid-area: one;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.quadrant-two {
    grid-area: two;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.quadrant-three {
    grid-area: three;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.quadrant-four {
    grid-area: four;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="menu">MENU</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="quadrant-one">I</div>
      <div class="quadrant-two">II</div>
      <div class="quadrant-three">III</div>
      <div class="quadrant-four">IV</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner-container {
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.